# How do I convert dictionary values to a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I convert the values of this dictionary to strings

```
d = {(0, 0): 'S', (1, 1): 'T', (2, 2): 'A', (3, 3): 'C', 
      (4, 4): 'K', (5, 5): 'O', (6, 6): 'V', (5, 7): 'E',
      (4, 8): 'R', (3, 9): 'F', (2, 10): 'L', (1, 11): 'O',
      (0, 12): 'W', (1, 13): 'T', (2, 14): 'E', (3, 15): 'S',
      (4, 16): 'T'}
```

How do I sort the output to this?

```
(0, 0), (0, 12),(1, 1),(1, 11) ....
```

I want to get the all the values in a one string 
the str method give me

```
dict_values(['S', 'T', 'A', 'C', 'K', 'O', 'V', 'E', 'R', 'F', 'L', 'O', 'W', 'T', 'E', 'S', 'T'])
```

Comment: What would the `str` output look like? There are many ways to go about this depending on what you want, specifically.

Comment: The values of your dictionary are already strings... What's your expected output and what have you tried?

Comment: you mean you want to sort the keys, and issue the values joined as a string

Comment: what about `"".join(d[k] for k in sorted(d))` ? or `"".join(v for _,v in sorted(d.items()))`

Comment: but then what is your sort criteria for tuple keys? because a simple sort gives `SWTOTALECFSKRTOEV`

Comment: the sort order you're describing is not `(0, 0), (0, 12),(1, 1),(1, 11)` BTW, it's rather `[(0, 0),
 (1, 1),
 (2, 2),
 (3, 3),
 (4, 4),
 (5, 5),
 (6, 6),
 (5, 7),
 (4, 8),
 (3, 9),
 (2, 10),
 (1, 11),
 (0, 12),
 (1, 13),
 (2, 14),
 (3, 15),
 (4, 16)]`

Answer (score 7):

In python 3.5 and higher, dictionaries preserve the order of keys as entered/added. So you could forget about the keys, and just do:

```
"".join(d.values())
```

But 1) it fails with older versions of Python and 2) I suppose that the keys are here for a purpose.

So I guess (I *really* guess) that you want to sort the values of your dictionary according to the *second value* of the tuple key (ignoring the first value).

```
d={(0, 0): 'S', (1, 1): 'T', (2, 2): 'A', (3, 3): 'C', (4, 4): 'K', (5, 5): 'O', (6, 6): 'V', (5, 7): 'E', (4, 8): 'R', (3, 9): 'F', (2, 10): 'L', (1, 11): 'O', (0, 12): 'W', (1, 13): 'T', (2, 14): 'E', (3, 15): 'S', (4, 16): 'T'}

result = "".join(v for _,v in sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[0][1]))
```

then:

```
>>> result
'STACKOVERFLOWTEST'
```

Comment: how can i get it by this sort (0, 0), (0, 12),(1, 1),(1, 11) .... ? the values and not the keys

Comment: @S.SAHT: `JF Fabre` has that sort in his answer.  The technique is available from any tutorial on sorting with keys.